# How to print the content of the portlet in liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet

I want the **print** functionality of the liferay portlet so that if we click on the print icon then it will print the content of the portlet, and also to show a new pop-up window while printing the content of the portlet.

Currently the icon is displayed, but clicking the print icon shows a null page. Can anyone tell me in details how we can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

When the user press on Print Button you need to do the following :

1- Open the portlet in Maximized Mode .

2- Check if the your Portlet mode is Maximized .

3- if it's use : `window.print();`